# Redux Observable: If the same action is dispatched multiple times, how do I cancel one of them?

Tags: rxjs, redux-observable

Say, I have this epic:

```js
export const getUserEpic = action$ => action$
  .ofType(t.GET_USER)
  .mergeMap(action => Observable
    .from(query.findUser(action.uid))
    .map(user => ({ type: t.GET_USER_SUCCESS, user }))
    .takeUntil(action$.ofType(t.GET_USER_CANCELLED))
```

Then, somewhere I dispatched `t.GET_USER` multiple times:

```js
dispatch({ type: t.GET_USER, uid: 'uid1' })
dispatch({ type: t.GET_USER, uid: 'uid2' })
dispatch({ type: t.GET_USER, uid: 'uid3' })
```

How do I cancel one of them? For example:

```js
dispatch({ type: t.GET_USER_CANCELLED, uid: 'uid2' })
```

AFAIK, `.takeUntil(action$.ofType(t.GET_USER_CANCELLED))` will cancel all `t.GET_USER` actions. I need to cancel only one.

Comment: You can use `switchMap` instead of `mergeMap` but it really depends on the logic of your app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `.filter()` predicate to only unsubscribe your mergeMap for the exact `uid` you are looking for:

```js
export const getUserEpic = action$ => action$
  .ofType(t.GET_USER)
  .mergeMap(action => Observable
    .from(query.findUser(action.uid))
    .map(user => ({ type: t.GET_USER_SUCCESS, user }))
    .takeUntil(
      action$
        .ofType(t.GET_USER_CANCELLED)
        .filter(act => act.uid === action.uid)
    )
```

Comment: That is absolutely brilliant. Thank you very much.